# How to send alerts on Kubernetes / Docker events?

Tags: kubernetes

Can anybody let me know how to config 
kubernetes pods to send alert to  slack channel ?

Thanks in Advance
Rishabh Gupta

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes dosn't provide out of the box slack integration.

There are few projects that you can use:

- https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/stable/kube-slack - runs on Kubernetes, watches for evnets and sends pod failures notifications to Slac
- https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/stable/kubewatch - similar project. depending on configuration can be quiet noisy

If you need more complex motoring you can use Prometheus and it's alert manager https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/notification_examples/

Answer (score 0):

### I would suggest go with Prometheus operator, as this project is cloud-native and give good hold on managing the alerts.

- Handles alerts with alert manager
- We can add data source with Grafana
- Write our own expressions for pod and microservices monitoring
- Works on **scraping** over http/s request
- we can easily expose the Applicaton metrics

https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus